# Hyrbid MPI / OpenMP

Tags: multithreading, cluster-computing, openmp, openmpi

I've been trying to use `OpenMPI` with `OpenMP` and when I run try to run 2 MPI processes and 4 threads on one machine, all threads are executed on the same core at 25% usage instead of on 4 separate cores. I was able to fix this using --enable-mpi-threads when building `OpenMPI`; but now I am having an issue with this being a duel CPU machine.

There are 8 cores per processor, 2 processors in each server. If I run 2 MPI processes and 8 threads then everything is fine as long as the 2 processes started on separate processors, but if I try and do 1 MPI process with 16 threads it reverts to stacking every thread on one core.

Has anyone had any experience running OpenMPI and OpenMP together?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly ? MPI distributes 16 works on 16 available cores what is wrong with that ?

Comment: Not enough memory; need to use some shared memory threads (OpenMP)